# Mongoose 4.1 mixed type schema upsert

Tags: mongoose, upsert

I need to find out how (if possible) do I 'upsert' mixed schema type.
I want to use schema-less approach but I need to either insert or update row based on attribute which I can provide.

Is this possible?

Now I have:

schema def.:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema
    ({
            any: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
        },
        {
            strict: false
        });
```

and when I do:

```
var modelo = new Modelo();

    modelo.markModified('extid');

    var outcome = modelo.update(
        {extid:  result.extid},
        result,
        {upsert: true},
        function (err, raw) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("persisted");
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

result being full object which I want to update/insert based on whether 'extid' exists.

the exception I am getting now is:

```
    oldCb(error, result ? result.result : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 });
      ^

TypeError: oldCb is not a function
```

I am asking straigtly through I have the feeling that it is not possible to use this approach with 'mixed type' schema. This is based on knowing that my model does not contain definition of 'update(..)' lambda function. Just 'save(..)'--which is working, but is just flushing data into the table without the logic I need.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my current knowledge, its not possible.
I have overcomed this just using 'mongodb' npm package instead of 'mongoose' which is working as expected.